# Date Time conversion in R 2010-11-08T09:24:57.000+01:00

Tags: r, datetime

Does anyone have an idea how I can convert this character to a Date and Time type in R?

```
2010-11-08T09:24:57.000+01:00
```

Comment: It this year-month-dayThour:minutes:seconds.subseconds+offsetashours:minutes? Are subseconds different from 0 in your data? Are there offsets that are not whole hours?

Comment: Maybe `as.POSIXct(gsub(":([0-9]{2})$","\\1","2010-11-08T09:24:57.000+01:00"),format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z")`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The only non-standard character is the last ":". You could use `gsub` to remove it, but I would use the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
a <-"2010-11-08T09:24:57.000+01:00"
a <-stri_replace_last_fixed(a, ":", "")
strptime(a,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z")
#[1] "2010-11-08 03:24:57"
```

If you insist on `gsub` and `regex`:

```
a<-gsub("(.*)\\:(:*)", "\\1\\2", a)
[1] "2010-11-08T09:24:57.000+0100"
```

Comment: Had commented a similar regex-based solution, but wasn't aware of `%OS`. +1.